# Syntax: const {} = variableName, can anyone explain or point me into the right direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What does this syntax mean in JavaScript (ES6 probably):

const {} = variablename;

I'm currently trying to get a grip of React. In a lot of examples I came across that syntax. For example:

```
const {girls, guys, women, men} = state;
```

Comment: It's called [destructuring assignment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First of all, this has nothing to do with React. It's part of ECMAScript 6 (or JavaScript 2015, if you prefer).

What you see here is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const {girls, guys, women, men} = state;

// Is the same as

const girls = state.girls;
const guys = state.guys;
const women = state.women;
const men = state.men;
```

---

You're probably going to encounter a similar pattern while studying React:

```
import { methodA, methodB } from "my-module";
```

In this case, you have a module called `my-module` that is exporting some functions. With the `import {} from` syntax, you choose which functions you want to import. Note that this is not a destructuring assignment, although it works similarly.

Comment: Also works with arrays: `const { a, b, c } = ['A', 'B', 'C'];`

Comment: It also works in function parameters `function({ a, b }) {}`

Comment: they are called [named-parameters](https://github.com/DrkSephy/es6-cheatsheet#named-parameters)

Comment: Please notice that the import syntax is entirely different from destructuring. While it is looking similar in shorthand notation, it uses `as` instead of `:` and is not nestable.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, but since OP was confused by destructuring I thought it could be helpful for him to learn also the import notation. I updated the answer to state that they are not the same thing.